# How do i prove this set has at most 2 elements?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry

Let $w,\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\delta,\epsilon >0$ such that $(w,\delta)\neq (\alpha,\epsilon)$

Define $G=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z-\alpha|=\epsilon \text{ and } |z-w|=\delta\}$

How do i prove that $G$ has at most 2 elements?

This is geometrically trivial, but i'm not sure how to prove this precisely..

Comment: May i ask what $(\omega,\delta)$ and $(\alpha,\epsilon)$ is?

Comment: @Thorben elements of $\mathbb C^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Start by taking conveniently $\alpha=0$ and $\epsilon=1$. If $z\in G$
then $z=e^{i\phi}$ for some $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$ and to be shown is
that there are at most two values for $\phi$ s.t. $\left|e^{i\phi}-w\right|=\delta$.
Setting $w=a+bi$ that comes to proving that $\left(\cos\phi-a\right)^{2}+\left(\sin\phi-b\right)^{2}=\delta^{2}$
has no more than two solutions in $[0,2\pi)$. Again it is convenient to solve this for a special case first, e.g. $w=a\in\mathbb R$. The more general cases can
be deduced from the special cases.

Comment: @drhad From your Hint, I derived $a\cos\phi + b\sin\phi = \delta^2 -1 - a^2 - b^2$. What should i do with this then?

Comment: it yields at most 4 solutions.. e.g. $\cos(5\pi/4)=\cos(3\pi /4)$

Comment: Firstly I repaired a mistake in my answer (sorry). Secondly it comes to solving $2a\cos\phi+2b\sin\phi=1+a^{2}+b^{2}-\delta^{2}$.

Comment: Since cosine and sine functions are not injective on $[0,2\pi)$, it leads that there are at most **4 solutions**. How come it implies 2 solutions at most?

Comment: Special case $b=0$ gives you the equality $2a\cos\phi=1+a^{2}-\delta^{2}$
and eventually $\cos\phi=c$ for some constant. On $[0,2\pi)$ there
are not more than two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an algebraic proof or a geometric one? Geometric, "intuitive" proofs can be precise too.

Here's the one you were probably thinking of. In the complex plane, the set of all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $|z-\alpha| = \epsilon$ is a circle centered at $\alpha$ and with radius $\epsilon$; similarly, the set of all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $|z-w| = \delta$ is a circle centered at $w$ and with radius $\delta.$ Therefore, the set $G$ is the points of intersection of the circles. Since $(w, \delta) \neq (\alpha, \epsilon),$ these circles are distinct, so they intersect at most twice, as requested. $\square$

An algebraic proof would involve writing $z = (x, y)$ and using definitions of magnitude, etc. It wouldn't be too pretty.

Comment: I meant a *formal* proof. I know those represent circles, and i think algebraic completeness of $\mathbb{C}$ would imply this  result, but i'm not sure how should an argument go.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove this would be to describe $G$ as the following intersection

$$G = \{z \in \mathbb C : |z-\alpha| = \epsilon\} =: A \cap B:= \{z \in \mathbb C : |z-w|= δ\}.$$

If you then reformulate $A$ and $B$ as the set of $\mathbb C$-rational points of two curves (specifically circles) and use Bézout's Theorem (ensuring you account for the points at infinity), the result will follow.

Comment: I feel like you are using a missile to break a stone.. this is an exercise in elementary complex analysis, in a chapter devoted to Mobius transformations. I definitely don't get your argument.. Do you any simple proof?

Comment: You're right that it's probably using more heavy machinery than need be, but once you know the result of Bézout, this is a very quick corollary. And is certainly 'precise'!

Comment: You are absolutely right, but i cannot understand your argument on my level.. there must be a simpler one

Comment: If you're happy stating that two distinct circles in the plane can intersect at most twice (this is essentially what Bézout will tell you), then it's equivalent to what I said. But that amounts to what Michael said below...

Answer (score 0):

A geometric way to look at it which can be made algebraically precise is to notice that $3$ different points determine the center of a circle on which they lie:

- The set of points which have equal distance from $2$ points is a line.
- $2$ different lines intersect at most in $1$ point.